# Как эффективно преобразовать QImage в numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

Как эффективно преобразовать `QImage` в `numpy.ndarray`?

Данный код неэффективен:

```
spisokPix = []
spisokPix2 = []
for y in range (self.currentPreview.height ()):
    spisokPix2.clear ()
    for x in range (self.currentPreview.width ()):
        color = self.currentPreview.pixelColor (x, y)
        spisokPix2.append (color.getRgb ()[:3][0])
    spisokPix.append (spisokPix2.copy ())
self.imageNda = np.array (spisokPix, np.uint8)
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге? Какова цель преобразований ?

Comment: для распознавания лица в полученном массиве

Comment: qimage2ndarray - это небольшое расширение Python для быстрого преобразования между QImages и numpy.ndarrays (в обоих направлениях). https://github.com/hmeine/qimage2ndarray

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: lirmon4ik, пожалуйста.